# How can I get reach for touch spells without spending an action per spell?

Tags: spellcasting, pathfinder-2e, reach, touch-attacks

Snaptongue Gripplis with the [Long Tongue](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2824) feat can deliver touch spells from 10 feet.

Aberrant Sorcerers can use the [Tentacular Limbs](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=517) focus spell<sup>1</sup> to get a similar effect.

**Is there any other way?**

The goal is to stay a bit further away with a caster, and to improve action efficiency (no need to Step if the recipient of Invisibility is 10 feet away). So [Reach Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=181) is not good, as it costs an action.

---

1. I am aware that casting it also takes an action, but there is an action benefit on the second spell

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Your choices are limited

Your best bet: the [**Spell Delivery Familiar Master Ability**](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx?ID=18), as T.E.D. points out. It's available to anyone with a familiar and a spare familiar ability slot, so it's really easy to access via the [Familiar Master archetype](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=60).

Your second best bet: bending the ask a bit, but the [**Spectral Hand**](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=295) spell does this very well. It has an action economy cost, but it can easily be frontloaded, or even cast before combat. An Imperial Sorcerer can use [Extend Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=507) on it to have it cast well before the combat too.

A third option (and the only remaining one I'm aware of and can find): [**Spellstrike**](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=755) for Magi (or through the Magus archetype) with a Reach weapon, and it's cousin, [**Spellshot from Eldritch Archer**](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1960). You could also be a [Starlit Span](https://2e.aonprd.com/HybridStudies.aspx?ID=4) to get that at a much longer range.

The Level 20 Option (courtesy of Ruse): [**Metamagic Mastery**](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=632) combined with Reach Spell. All the benefits of Reach Spell without the action cost! Obviously, this takes forever to come online and so probably isn't worth building around, but it might be more worth aiming for in a higher level game if you have some other mitigation option in the meantime (e.g. Spectral Hand).

Comment: This is the most complete answer, including things that are not easy to find with the text search like Spellshot.

Comment: Ah. I knew about the hand (and was in the process of editing it in after looking up its info), but didn't know about Spellstrike. Kind of thought reach weapons were out of bounds if the reach tongue was though (question says "a bit further than 10 feet"). Wouldn't be shocked if there isn't also some manner of rune (or artifact?) that adds range to touch spells stored in a staff too.

Comment: @T.E.D. - the way I interpreted the question, Long Tongue and Tentacular Limbs are positive examples of what András is looking for. A reach weapon seems to be along the same lines (with Spellstrike).

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, I interpreted "a bit further away" to mean "a bit further away than in my previous 2 examples". It would be nice to get a clarification on that point.

Comment: @T.E.D. I meant a bit further away _than the usual touch range_ (which is adjacent only)

Answer (score 4):

Witches can have their familiars deliver touch spells via the [Spell Delivery](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx?ID=18) familiar master ability. Other spellcasters with familiars can as well, but Witches come with the familiar out of the box, and can replace them the next day rather than waiting a week if the intended target decides to literally "kill the messenger". It costs an action to command the familiar to deliver the spell though, and the familiar will then have to use their 2 actions to go and touch the target.

Most (all?) spellcasters can gain the [Reach Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=181) class skill (at level 1). This is a metamagic feat which makes touch spells have a range of 30 feet, at the same cost of an extra action (making the combined cast take their entire turn, for most offensive spells)

For most pure spellcasters, that 1-action penalty isn't going to be a huge penalty, because even though they could just use that action to walk up and touch the victim themselves, they are squishy and don't want to be in melee if they can help it. Also, touch spells are more powerful than ranged spells, so it wouldn't be right to give them range totally cost-free. However, if you really don't like chewing up all your actions *every turn* to use it, there are some other options I know of...

### [Spectral Hand](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=295)

[image]

This is a level 2 (arcane or occult) spell. For a 2-action cast, you have a disembodied hand (think [Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thing_(The_Addams_Family))) that will automatically deliver touch spells for you for 1 minute. It doesn't appear to require an action to tell it to do so, and its range is a whopping 120 feet.

The price you pay for this is that if the hand somehow gets damaged at any point in that 1 minute, it will be destroyed, and hurt you a bit (1D6) in the process. Since its a 2nd level spell, of course a further cost is that casting it costs you a 2nd level (or greater) spell slot, so you can't just spam these Things all day.

### Leshies!

[image]

Reach is available as an ability for Leshy *familiars* for Leaf Order druids who take the [Leshy Familiar Secrets](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1713) feat. If you do that, the little guy's reach is a much more comfortable 15 feet! Combine that with spell delivery, and yes you still have to blow all *your* actions, but your Leshy still has one action left over. Pimp him up enough and you could make good use of the extra action.

### Get it off me! Get it off me!

[image]

If you don't mind your familiar potentially being targeted (if you're not a Witch, it takes a week to replace a dead one), you could give it the [spellcasting](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx?ID=34) master ability. This *does* use up all the familiar's actions (unless its a 1-action touch spell) but only 1 of yours, **potentially allowing you to get off 2 damaging spells in one turn**.
That's great, so of course the drawbacks are commensurately harsh. The spell has to be a great deal lower than you could normally cast, so you probably have more damaging ranged options, and it can only do this once per day. Also you have to use a previous turn to position the minion on top of the target, and then hope the prospective victim doesn't move or kill it. But either one of those will burn at least one of the *target's* actions, which is kinda nice too. And what else useful were you going to do with that 3rd action that turn anyway?

I've depicted this with a [Spellslime](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx?ID=3&Specific=true), as their 30 foot speed, immunity to precision and crits, and ability to heal themselves a bit when you refocus makes them an interesting choice for a minion punching-bag.

### [Haste Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=147)

[image]

I feel like this is the dumb answer, but if you reallly don't like losing your last action each turn when you use Reach Spell, perhaps at least compare the effort involved in all these other soultions to what you could get by just casting a 1-minute level 3 [Haste spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=147) on yourself. That gives you 1 more action after the reach spell to use for a move or a strike.

Of course nothing's stopping you from picking one of the other options *and then casting Haste*, so they still are worth looking at, even if just casting Haste is easier.

Comment: > If you don't mind your familiar potentially being targeted (it takes a week to replace a dead one),

Unless you're a Witch, in which case, the Familiar comes back whenever you do your daily preparations.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz - Good point. There are a lot of little things like that IMHO Witch-haters aren't entirely accounting for. Of course for the rest of that day the Witch in question will effectively be without their spellbook...

Answer (score 2):

## For one ally: Nymph's Token

It is the 1st level focus spell of Nymph Sorcerers, when heightened to level 4 you can use touch spells on the holder of the token.

Unfortunately, it takes two actions to cast and you need to be adjacent to give the token to your ally.

Comment: Only useful defensively, but sometimes that's what you need, so +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Casting [Enlarge](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=102) also increases your reach in 3.5, Pathfinder and Pathfinder 2e

Comment: Another dead simple spell option I should have thought of!  I will say that the [Clumsy 1](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=3) can be a bit of an issue as you are probably already squishy enough and won't be happy with your AC and reflex saves being made even worse.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the two you already list:

- [Spell Delivery](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx?ID=18) Master Ability for Familiars

> If your familiar is in your space, you can cast a spell with a range of touch, transfer its power to your familiar, and command the familiar to deliver the spell. If you do, the familiar uses its 2 actions for the round to move to a target of your choice and touch that target. If it doesn’t reach the target to touch it this turn, the spell has no effect.

- [Seven-Part-Link](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3728) is quite limited, as a Thaumaturge 16 feat it allows you to do it to only up to 6 willing allies, but it allows reach delivery between those, so it could work to deliver, for example, *Invisibility* to your allies as requested.

> In addition to the normal effects of Paired Link, if a linked ally casts a spell with a range of touch, they can target linked allies within 30 feet with that spell.

Comment: Unfortunately, OP is looking for something other than Reach Spell (mentioned in their question), but Spell Delivery meets the bill (as all of our answers have noted )

Comment: Spell Delivery costs an action, just like Reach Spell